# What to do when adjusted $R^{2}$ is infinity?

Tags: python, r-squared

I am calculating Adjusted $R^{2}$ from an $R^{2}$ value in Python. The code is like below:

```
def adjusted_r2(r2, X, y): 
    p = X.shape[1]
    n = len(y)
    r2_adj = 1 - (1-r2) * float(n-1) / (n-p-1)
    return r2_adj
```

While running this I have the following warning for a single case.

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  #r2_adj = 1 - (1-r2)*float(n-1)/(n - p - 1)
```

For this specific case `n=27`, `p=26` thus `(n-p-1)` becomes zero. So the divide by zero warning results.

I am doing this to evaluate the accuracy of my machine learning model (26 predictors and 1 target). I can twist the training, test set split ratio of the `train_test_split()` function to avoid this error. But is it necessary?

What should be the most meaningful thing to do in such a case?

Edit:
- I am using Random Forest and Decision Tree ML algorithms.

Comment: Drop the predictor(s) which are the same metric as your target.

Comment: There is no predictor that is same as the target. However, I have few predictors that are highly correlated. I will eliminate those highly correlated ones and will compare the results, i.e., the difference in accuracy between the model consisting all predictors and model consisting only non-collinear predictors.

Comment: If "n=26, p=27" then (n-p-1) would be -2 not 0

Comment: Ok. it should be n=27, p=26. :) I am correcting the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You recognize that your model is vastly over-specified, and you have virtually exhausted your degrees of freedom, because each *single observation* in your outcome variable has 0.963 variables "explaining" it, and you either go collect more data, or drop the number of predictor variables, until you have enough statistical power to make any actual inference.

A heuristic is no replacement for actual power calculations, but a crass rule of thumb is 20 observations per variable.

Comment: Very good observation, Alexis. I am working on multiple data sets. Looks like, I have to drop this specific dataset even after reducing my predictors.

Comment: @Narnia_Optimus More generally, I suggest you reconsider the use of R2 & adjusted R2 for your model comparisons. Since you are already splitting your dataset, you can calculate the error (MSE, RMSE, MAE, whichever) in the holdout dataset and use that as the basis for evaluting the models.

Comment: You are right, the divide by zero is happening only for the test set because it has fewer observations than the training data.

Comment: I actually have calculated all of them (r2 and adjusted r2 for both training and test sets, and MAE, MSE, RMSE) and was trying out different measures, but your last comment is more helpful for me than this question. Thanks a lot.